# How to get feature from GUID on Project Online

Tags: feature, project-online

In Project Server on-prem I know how to get a feature/web part from its Guid using PowerShell, but since we can't use PowerShell in Project Online (right?), how can I see the name of a feature or web part from just its Guid?

The context is that some project sites are not being created, and the error in the queue says that it's due to some feature with a given Guid. This is why I want to get the feature name from its Guid, so I can find the feature that is responsible for these errors.

Comment: Have you tried installing and using the SharePoint Online Management Shell? Project Online are just special SharePoint sites.

Comment: I'm not trying to install anything. Some project sites are not being created, and from the error in the queue, I can see that this is due to some feature with a certain Guid. I'll edit the question to give these details.